# How does Round robin policy of MPIO work in Windows 2008 R2

Tags: load-balancing, round-robin, mpio

I have a Dell server with a 1G dual port iSCSI adapter. I have installed the NIC driver and using Microsoft iSCSI initiator, map few luns to both the ports and enable MPIO. The target I used was Microsoft iSCSI Software target. In MPIO, I set the policy as Round robin.

Now, I use IOMeter to start IO on all the luns. WHile the IO is running, I pull one cable from a port. Now, what I see is that IO stops on the connected port as well and then resumes after 30 seconds.

My question here is, since Round robin policy is a load balancing policy, why does the IO pause for 30 seconds on the connected port? Is it possible to eliminate the 30 second period entirely?

Comment: This depends heavily on what type of storage array you're connecting to... Dual controllers? Active/Active or Active/Passive?

Comment: I have been using Microsoft iSCSI software target, which I understand is Active/Active target. Also, I had been using a single NIC interface  on the server where the target was configured.

Comment: Sorry then, I'm at a loss... I'm fairly certain it shouldn't be behaving that way. You may want to try a different test, like IOmeter to see of results are the same...

Comment: I have been using IOMeter to run traffic on this setup.